# Quick date formatting thing

Tags: php

How do I convert `20120204` to something like `Mon, 04 Feb 2012 00:00:00 +0000`?
Version of PHP is 5.4.

Comment: I looked through date, strftime, and I can't think of any sane way to do it that doesn't contain probably stuff like `$year = (int) substr('20120204', 0, 4);`, was hoping there was a better way (to get that string into a unix timestamp format or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$> php -r 'echo date("r", mktime(0,0,0,2,4,2012));'` will give you `Sat, 04 Feb 2012 00:00:00 +0530` ...

You can check detail syntax of [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) here

also before applying date you might also want to check this method:
`$> php -r 'print_r(strptime("20120204", "%Y%m%d"));'` which will give you components of input data format you have

Answer (score 1):

It's generally recommended to use PHP's [DateTime](http://uk.php.net/datetime) class for Date handling/manipulation. So you would do something like this

```
$dateString = '20120204';
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymd', $dateString );
echo $dateObject->format( 'r' );
```